# Is a new transition always applied before the new value?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Suppose I'm using `transition`, to smoothly change an element's position on hover. I also **change the value of `transition` itself** to achieve a different animation in each direction.

It seems like when I move the mouse over the elements, the **new** `transition` value is used for the "forward" transition, and when I un-hover, the **old** value is used for the "reverse" transition.

I couldn't find much documentation about this. Is the order guaranteed?

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: left 1s linear, top 1s ease-in-out;
}
:hover div {
  top: 150px;
  left: 400px;
  transition: left 1s linear, top 1s linear;
}
div:nth-child(2) { transition-delay: 0.1s; }
div:nth-child(3) { transition-delay: 0.2s; }
div:nth-child(4) { transition-delay: 0.3s; }
```

```html
Hover on me!
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "new" and "old" here? The transition that applies in each case is the one that matches the applicable selector.

Comment: I mean that all 3 properties change their values when I hover on the element, and it's not intuitively clear in which order the changes are applied, at least coming from background experience with a framework such as Core Animation where ["model" and "presentation" layers are separate things](https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animations-explained/#first-things-first) and the parameters of an animation are set up before the animation starts running. I think your answer makes sense though...

Comment: I think the key difference here is that thinking about transition in terms of "animations *starting* while the element is/isn't :hovered" is the wrong way to think about it. Still, I don't think standard documentation is really explicit about this (nor is it easy to search for) so there's room for a good answer here.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] all 3 properties change their values when I hover on the element, and it's not intuitively clear in which order the changes are applied, at least coming from background experience with a framework such as Core Animation where "model" and "presentation" layers are separate things and the parameters of an animation are set up before the animation starts running. I think your answer makes sense though...
>
> I think the key difference here is that thinking about transition in terms of "animations starting while the element is/isn't :hovered" is the wrong way to think about it.

You are right, the paradigm you're used to (an MVC paradigm) doesn't really apply to CSS. At least not at the level where you as a CSS "writer" are affected. The relevant spec for this, by the way, is [CSS Transitions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/)

In CSS, changes to CSS properties apply immediately. Transitions allow you to apply a change to a value over some duration. In your case, you have four divs who are all set to be 30px from the top and 0px from the left edges of the screen.

On hover, thanks to your `:hover div` selector, new styles apply. Normally they'd apply instantaneously, but because you gave them a transition, it happens over a duration. You can see each one move individually thanks to the `transition-delay` you gave some of them, as well. To make it even easier to see, I changed the color of each div to be unique. It should be pretty clear which ones move first.

As soon as you remove your mouse, the `:hover` pseudo-class no longer applies, and so the styles under `div` are re-applied. Again, they would be instantaneously applied, but the `transition` you set (along with the `transition-delay on 3 of the 4 divs) changes that to occur over a longer duration. So, just as when the` :hover` styles apply, the red div moves first, then the others after an increasing 0.1s delay each.

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: left 1s linear, top 1s ease-in-out;
}
:hover div {
  top: 150px;
  left: 400px;
  transition: left 1s linear, top 1s linear;
}
div:nth-child(2) { transition-delay: 0.1s; background: blue; }
div:nth-child(3) { transition-delay: 0.2s; background: green; }
div:nth-child(4) { transition-delay: 0.3s; background: yellow; }
```

```html
Hover on me!
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: The question was primarily about the value of `transition` that also changes on hover, but your answer doesn't really seem to address that point, it just explains what a transition is.

Comment: @jtbandes I tried to respond to your question as best I understood it. If the answer here doesn't address the question, then please update the question to clarify what you are asking, as it is otherwise unclear.